# Combine/merge PDF files in Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, software-rec

Is there a painless way to combine/merge PDF files in Windows?   I understand that pdftk will do it on Linux.

Comment: This question appears to have gone not constructive due to the unlimited amount of possible answers. For a more comprehensive list see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software

Comment: How could this question possibly be "off-topic"?!

Comment: @CJ7: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic "asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation" is apparently not on-topic. (But I do come back to this question every month to be reminded of the name of the tool I downloaded to solve this problem!)

Comment: FYI [Free software for selecting and combining pages from multiple PDFs into a single PDF](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/106/903)

Comment: If you need correctly free merge PDF's, filenames of which is numbers without leading zeros (for example, `4.pdf`, not `004.pdf`, `14.pdf`, not `014.pdf`), see [**my answer**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/66401/23324). Thanks.

Comment: [List of PDF software - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software "List of PDF software - Wikipedia")

Answer (score 136, accepted):

There are quite a few free options, as well as some good commercial ones:

**Web-based (Free)**

- [BCL Premium PDF Merge](http://www.pdfonline.com/premium/Merge.aspx) Merge 2 PDF documents. Max 10MB/file. Limit of 20 merges/day
- [MergePDF](http://www.mergepdf.net/). Merge up to 10 files. Max limit of 5MB/file. (Registration required)

**Desktop tools (free)**

- [Booklet Creater](http://bookletcreator.com/). Merges files to create a booklet. Rearranges pages to that you can print and fold to create a simple booklet.
- [PDF Sam](http://www.pdfsam.org/). Also known as "PDF Split & Merge". FOSS tool for splitting and merging PDFs. Windows & Mac. Console and GUI interfaces. On Windows, the installer by default installs Ad-Aware Security Toolbar, sets Lavasoft SecureSearch as homepage, new tabs, and default search provider.
- [Swift PDF](http://www.derring.com/swiftpdf/). Combines multiple images (JPG, GIF, etc.) into a single PDF.

  Editor's note, 5/1/2017: Swift PDF was last updated in 2006 and was compatible with Windows 95.  The original link is dead and the product appears to no longer be supported.  However, it is still downloadable at https://swift-pdf.en.softonic.com/
- [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/). FOSS power tool. Command line only. Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD. Windows GUI versions exist, including a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdftk_builder_portable) and the [official free version](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

There are also a lot of commercial tools.

Comment: Just tried PDF Sam and the resulting PDF it generates is version 1.5 at minimum, when I needed version 1.4. In case you need that, on Windows you can use PDF Version Converter, available here: http://www.freeware-guide.com/dir/util/pdf.html

Comment: Just installed PDF Sam, and as far as I can see, the installer no longer includes any toolbars or other browser related garbage.

Comment: I had to get swift pdf from here: swift-pdf.software.informer.com, but +1 for that. I can't find another tool that works for images.

Comment: I'd like the pdftk command line version so I could call from another application/script but on the site I only found the GUI version... Where can I find the command line one?

Comment: MergePDF and PDF Hammer require sign up to use. Booklet Creator isn't a web tool. It seems that only the last web option (now called easyPDF cloud) is the only one that works without signup.

Comment: *Best solution as 06/20/2019 for Windows 10*

* Download Debunu PDF Tools Free : https://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-tools/free/

* Go to install folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Debenu\PDF Tools
* Give administrator privileges to PDFTools.exe and PDFToolsShell.exe
* Select 2/+ PDFs and right click > Debunu PDF Tools > Split and merge > Merge Selected files.
* Just click OK in next window. Your merged PDF (MergeOutput) is right there in same folder as files.

Comment: the PDF hammer link no longer links to a free webapp :(

Comment: swift pdf link seems to be dead

Comment: Currently pdftk free version has a GUI too.  https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger

Answer (score 51):

`pdftk.exe` is available for Windows as well. See here: http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/#packages and here: http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/pdftk-1.41.exe.zip

Here is an example commandline for `pdftk.exe`. It merges all PDF files in the current directory into a combined one:

```
pdftk.exe *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

Another one:

```
\\myserver\c$\path\to\pdftk.exe ^
   c:\path\to\input1.pdf ^
   d:\path\to\input2.pdf ^
   cat ^
   output ^
   e:\path\to\combined.pdf
```

Ghostscript can also combine multiple input PDFs (and PostScript files) into one output PDF:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
        -dBATCH ^
        -dNOPAUSE ^
        -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
        -sOutputFile=output.pdf ^
        [...more Ghostscript CLI options as needed...] ^
        input1.pdf ^
        input2.pdf ^
        input3.ps ^
        input4.eps ^
        input5.pdf
```

---

#### Update suggested by @sunk818

There is a GUI for `pdftk` named [PDFTK Builder](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdftk_builder_portable). This essentially builds a command line based on your option choices for you and executes:

[image: PDFTK Builder]

---

#### My own update

Since I originally posted this answer, `pdftk` has undergone further developments.

1. The application's name changed to ***PDFtk Server*** (the command line tool is still called `pdftk`).
2. There is now version 2.02 available.
3. The developers now offer their own GUI for Windows, called ***[PDFtk Pro](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-pro/)***.

Comment: pdftk was already suggested in this answer - http://superuser.com/questions/34284/combine-merge-pdf-files-in-windows/34294#34294

Comment: I know. But user1413 seemed to have missed pdftk to be available on Windows as well. Therefor I emphasized that point by repeating it.

Comment: There's a portable version here: http://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdftk_builder_portable - I used it merge PDF via the GUI provided. Worked quite well.

Comment: @sunk818: Thanks, I included your suggested edit into the answer (and then some).

Comment: The join feature of PDFTK Builder is buggy.  I tried to join pages 1-2,3 of PDF1 followed by pages 3,2,1 of PDF2 and it ended up saving pages 1,2,3 of PDF1 followed by page 3 of PDF2 followed by pages 2,1 of PDF1.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Does the following command line work? **`pdftk A=pdf1.pdf B=pdf2.pdf cat A1-3 B3 B2 B1 output merged.pdf`**

Comment: That works fine, it's definitely a bug in PDFTK Builder.

Comment: As of right now, PDFtk is available in 3 versions: PDFtk Server, PDFtk Free and PDFtk Pro. PDFtk Server, as you wrote in your answer, is the command line tool, which makes it harder to use, but it's powerful and free. The other two offer a graphical interface; the difference is that the Free version is limited to splitting and merging, while the Pro version (which costs $3.99) also offers rotating pages, adding watermarks/stamps, and setting passwords. Would you mind updating your answer? Otherwise I can suggest an edit if you prefer.

Answer (score 9):

Try [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/), which comes for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

The basic version is free, I'm pretty sure that the basic version will meet your needs.  You will need to have Java installed on your computer to run this program.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html) to perform lots of manipulations on your PDFs for free.

Use the "Merge PDF Files" button (button #1) in the screenshot below.

[image: PDFill PDF Tools screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I found the best for me: [PDF Split and Merge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfmerge/)

[image]

> PDF Split and Merge tool is implemented using the PdfSharp library and is either GUI or command driven.It is useful for automated document creation.It allows bookmarks from the input pdfs to be imported and flexibly embedded in the destination document.

It just merges or splits PDF files, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

[PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) will do the trick -- you can print multiple documents to a single PDF.  Relatively painless :)

Answer (score 3):

Also [this program named pdfbinder](http://code.google.com/p/pdfbinder/) proved to be useful. It has a simple commandline interface for input and uses the same engine as the [PDF Split and Merge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfmerge/) already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can do this with Adobe Acrobat. I assume that you don't want to pay for this if it's the only use you have. You highlight your PDF files, right-click and select `Combine files in Acrobat...`:

[image]

Ghostscript, available on Linux and Windows, should be able to concatenate them, but it uses complicated command-line functions. You can use CutePDF, which has a free version, but I believe the Professional (paid) version is the only one that will concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

This little app I found with a Google search let me merge image files into a single PDF, which it didn't look like some of these options would. It's very limited, but it did the trick for me just now.

http://www.pdfmate.com/free-pdf-merger.html

Comment: Contains virusses, thanks: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/f74dac023102a5a3535c63baa2f77b7b764586831052d24361bb929406e1414e/analysis/