# Free PDF/A printer for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, software-rec, print-to-pdf

does someone of you know a freely available program that installs itself as a printer on Windows and is able to produce PDF/A documents?? Moreover there should be the possibility to merge documents (I.e. multiple Microsoft Word/Excel docs).

I know there exists already a plugin for Open Office Writer written by sun. But the problem there is that you cannot merge multiple docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option for Word and Excel docs in the [free add-in for Office from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en) that adds **Save As PDF** to the menu.  This works very well, with Word headings being turned into PDF bookmarks and so on.

Otherwise I'd recommend [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) which installs itself as a printer on Windows.  You can also use PDFCreator to merge several documents into a single PDF by collecting several prints using the **Wait - Collect** button and then saving them a single PDF.

[image]

Comment: Is it PDF or PDF/A?

Answer (score 4):

pdfprinter: [pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or [dopdf](http://www.dopdf.com/)
merging / splitting pdfs: [pdfmerge](http://pdfmerge.sourceforge.net/)

a similar question would be [34284](https://superuser.com/questions/34284/combine-merge-pdf-files-in-windows).

Comment: Is it PDF or PDF/A?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by PDF/A... Do you just mean Adobe?

Anyway, I have used [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) for years now and love it!

Comment: PDF/A is a subset of PDF designed for long-term archiving: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A

Answer (score 2):

I've used [CutePDF writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/download/CuteWriter.exe) for a while now, and I havn't had any troubles yet. I prefer to use the [Save-to-PDF Addin](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en) (as suggested by Dave Webb) for my Office files though- less hassle.

Comment: Is it PDF or PDF/A?