# Convert selection to PDF in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extensions, print-to-pdf

There are Google Chrome plugins that convert entire web pages into PDF, but are there any plugins or other software that convert only the selected area in a web page to PDF?

Comment: I guess if you install any PDF printer and [print selection](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/print-selection-in-google-chrome.html). Or you can take a screenshot, save as an image and then convert the image to PDF.

Comment: in google chrom I used default printer, but could not find print selection, any printers suggestion?

Comment: I don't use Chrome personally, but according to Google (search) there's a [few](http://www.justinmontgomery.com/ctrlshiftp-to-print-selection-in-google-chrome) [things](http://www.zimbio.com/Google+Chrome/articles/cF1F_9Znp5a/Google+Chrome+Tips+Tricks+Print+Selection) you can try.

Comment: yes, thx, I have just found it and wanted to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify an operating system. While this answer should work across Windows/OSX/Linux, specific program recommendations will be for Windows because that's what I primarily use.

---

The most basic and program independent method is to install a [PDF printer](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=pdf%20printer). I won't really [recommend](https://superuser.com/questions/50326/free-pdf-a-printer-for-windows) any specific one, but I have used [Primo PDF](http://www.primopdf.com/download.aspx) on Windows in the past.

To convert a selected area, well, there's two ways, both generally program independent. You can select the text and print the selection to the PDF printer, or you can take a screenshot, crop it and print the result to PDF.

Chrome has been known to cause users to struggle with printing only a selection. [There's](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/print-selection-in-google-chrome.html) [a few](http://www.justinmontgomery.com/ctrlshiftp-to-print-selection-in-google-chrome) [ways](http://www.zimbio.com/Google+Chrome/articles/cF1F_9Znp5a/Google+Chrome+Tips+Tricks+Print+Selection) to do so, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> if you're on Windows. There's also a few plugins that allow printing only the selection.