# Combine multiple screenshots into same image file or pdf file with greenshot

Tags: pdf, images, greenshot

I need to combine multiple partial screenshots into the same file with Greenshot. I would rather prefer that file to be .pdf. Since I do not think greenshot allows creation of pdf files, I am okay with JPEG or PNG format as well, as long as resulting file is readable.

Comment: Have you checked the [Greenshot Help](http://getgreenshot.org/help/)? You might find the section on "adding graphics to a screenshot" to be interesting...

Comment: I did, it just adds any window or picture on top of the picture in hand. What I need is a .pdf-like file consisting of various screenshots.

Comment: Why not just paste your screenshots sequentially into Word, Publisher, or PowerPoint? Microsoft Office, since Office 2010 at least, has supported save-as-PDF.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I do not have it installed in my computer now. I will try that as the last option.

Comment: LibreOffice - probably most OpenForks - can also export as PDF.

Comment: You don't have to install anything if you use Google's Office software since it runs in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, Greenshot does not support combination of multiple images into one document (except adding an image onto a screenshot).

Windows 10 allows "printing" multiple images into a PDF file, though. For earlier Windows versions, you'll probably need 3rd party software like [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). (I have not tried it, but from the website it seems it could do the job, plus it is free and open source. [This superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/34294/247669) lists some more tools.)

If you're familiar with the windows command line, it should even be possible to use [Greenshot's external command plugin](https://getgreenshot.org/2013/01/28/how-to-use-the-external-command-plugin-to-send-screenshots-to-other-applications/) to send screenshots directly to the PDFtk command line interface.

---

Disclosure: I am a member of the Greenshot development team.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer! It seems like something which should be possible in the built in image editor, but the image editor only has resize image which stretches stuff.